# Cannot install package using docker compose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

My web app uses Node.js and MongoDB. I am pulling mongo image from [docker image hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/). When I build an image of my node app it runs fine alone. However when I start up containers using compose it gives the following error. Isn't it supposed to install the packages when image is built from Dockerfile?

> web_1  | module.js:457
>   web_1  |     throw err;
>
> web_1  |     ^
>
> web_1  |
>
> web_1  | Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
>
> web_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
>
> web_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
>
> web_1  |     at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
>
> web_1  |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>
> web_1  |     at Object. (/worklog/worklog.js:7:14)
>
> web_1  |     at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
>
> web_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
>
> web_1  |     at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
>
> web_1  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
>
> web_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)

Dockerfile

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /worklog

WORKDIR  /worklog

RUN npm install mongoose \
    express \
    body-parser \
    express-session \
    method-override \ 
    connect-mongo \
    mongodb

COPY login.html worklog.html workloglist.html worklog.js /worklog/

ENV NODE_VERSION 6.3.1

EXPOSE 4000

CMD npm, start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
web:
  build: .
  command: node worklog.js
  volumes:
    - .:/worklog
  ports:
    - "4000:4000"
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    PORT: 4000
```

Comment: Try "docker-compose rm web && docker-compose rm db && docker-compose build && docker-compose up" to start with a clean environment. If you "docker ps" can you see the db_1 container running?

Comment: I tried it but same result again. I saw that it does not pull packages from archive when I use `docker-compose up` or your command. Yes I can see db_1 running.

Comment: Try adding a "docker-compose pull" before the build command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volumes

```
volumes:
  - .:/worklog
```

is basically masking everything you installed to /worklog in the build with the files on the host, including /worklog/node_modules if any. You could try

```
volumes:
  - .:/worklog
  - /worklog/node_modules
```

which I think overlays the /worklog/node_modules from the container on top of the directory mounted from the host again making the node_modules visible to the app.